# Restyle feature when overzooming OpenLayers 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers

[image: Example image]

In the above image, the left is a self-created render of local mbtiles data using openlayers 4.6.4. On the right is a leaflet showing of similar content.

The issue I'm running into is that I'm trying to have the width of the road (pictured in Orange) stay consistent or enlarge when overzooming on the data of the left image, which has a maximum tile detail level of 14. In the end, it should look similar as on the right.

Within the styles of the OpenLayers, I'm currently applying the following change to the width of the line according to the zoom:

`var zoomAdjustment = Math.max(0, (map.getView().getZoom() - 13) * 2);
     width += zoomAdjustment;`

This works, although needs to be tweaked. However, the problem is that the features are not reloaded or restyled after zoomLevel 14 has been reached, so it will stay a consistent size regardless of zooming in or out after zoomLevel 14 instead of becoming larger to signify the size of the road itself.

Is there a way to 'redraw' the feature to enlarge it in some way but keep its position and the geometry of it the same?

So far, I've done the following:
- Looked into the Style and Feature and how to possibly redraw them, however I am getting none the wiser from reading the API on how to do it.
- Attempted to scale the width, but as said above it doesn't continue scaling after it can't find anymore tiles (which is logical due to the nature of how the data is loaded)

I am going to currently attempt to observe the map and manually override the style of the features once it's changed it's zoom beyond 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was just as simple as overwriting the style every time the zoom adjusted by observing the map like this:

```
map.on('change', () => { 
     var zoomAdjustment = Math.max(0, (map.getView().getZoom() - 14) * 2);
     width += zoomAdjustment;
     map.getLayers().forEach((layer) => { 
        layer.setStyle(style);
     });
});
```